# Can we apply case in two different queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to fetch data from two different tables on the basis of some conditions

CASE 1 : If a2 is present in both the tables then we will give preference to this and will ignore a1

TableA

| columnA | name |
| --- | --- |
| st1 | a1 |
| st2 | a2 |

TableB

| data1 | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 |
| 2 | a2 |

Output:

| data1 | name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | a2 |

CASE 2 : If a2 is not present then we will give preference to a1.

TableA

| columnA | name |
| --- | --- |
| st1 | a1 |
| st2 | a2 |

TableB

| data1 | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 |

Output:

| data1 | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 |

I'm using below query. It is fetching both the rows in CASE 1:

```
           SELECT t2.data1, t2.name FROM TableA t1 join TableB t2 on t1.name = t2.name
           UNION 
           SELECT t2.data1, t2.name FROM TableA t1 join TableB t2 on t1.name = t2.name WHERE t2.name = 'a2'
```

Is there any way to run one query like we do in case? I don't want to use UNION.

Comment: What if `A` has neither `a1` nor `a2`?

Comment: then it will return nothing

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want only rows from `B` based on what is available in `A`.  For your simple example, this seems to suffice:

```
select b.*
from b
where (b.name = 'a2' and
       exists (select 1 from a where a.name = b.name)
      ) or
      b.name = 'a1';
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by using `MAX` Function

Data Insertion:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (columnA CHAR(5), NAME CHAR(2))

INSERT INTO @T VALUES('st1','a1'),('st2','a2')

DECLARE @T1 TABLE (data1 INT, NAME CHAR(2))

INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES('1','a1'),('2','a2')
```

Query:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN T.NAME=T1.NAME  THEN data1 END) AS data1,
MAX(CASE WHEN T.NAME=T1.NAME  THEN T1.NAME  END) AS NAME
FROM @T T
LEFT JOIN @T1 T1 ON T.NAME=T1.NAME
```